# Efficient existing rating system for multiplayer?

Tags: game-design, multiplayer, leaderboards, ranking

I would like to add a rating for online version of a board game. In this game there are many game rooms each normally having 3-4 people.

So I expect that player's rating adjustments (RA) should depends on

1. Rating of opponents in the game room
2. Number of players in game room and final place of a player
3. Person gets rating increase if he plays more games and more frequently
4. If a person leaves a game room (disconnect) before the game ends he should get punished with a high rating decrease

I have found two related questions in here

[Developing an ELO like point system for a multiplayer gaming site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/developing-an-elo-like-point-system-for-a-multiplayer-gaming-site)

[Simplest most effective way to rank and measure player skill in a multi-player environment?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3788/simplest-most-effective-way-to-rank-and-measure-player-skill-in-a-multi-player-e)

**Please, let me know what would be the most appropriate existing rating model to refer.**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @TrevorPowell, it is in bold

Comment: You haven't presented an issue which needs to be solved.  You've stated what you want to do in the numbered list, so just do that?  I guess I just don't understand what you mean by "this issue", because I don't see an issue to be solved, here.

Answer (score 4):

The ELO system is used by the FIDE (World Chess Federation) as ranking systems and League of Legends is using a system based on ELO. I have used it for local long-term game tournamets. ELO is a good system. If you want penalize those who play less, you can modify the ranking every certain time to remove points and positions to those who deserve it.

Comment: WIKIPedia says it is only for games of two people. I have 3-4 in one game room

Comment: Think about this. You have player A, B and C. A scores 45, B 67 and C 36. Then, B gets two victories, one against A and other against C; A beats C buts loses against B (1-1); and finally, C loses against A and B.

Comment: this makes no sense to me

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov You can calculate a 3vs3 match as multiple smaller 1vs1 matches.

Comment: Exactly that's what I was trying to explain.

Comment: @Mr.Beast, now I understand, thanks to amusero. But I don't think in my case it is equivalent

Comment: Isn't a form of ELO used in the StarCraft 2 rating system?  Actually, researching how SC2 ranks millions of players would probably be a good route to take.

Comment: @Philip, good advice

Comment: Unfortunately the SC2's ranking system is not transparent and nobody really now how it works in depth. However it looks like a program exists http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=334561 maybe play a bit with it to see if you can grab some ideas